# Is a SQL query still called a "query" when doing a deletion, update or insertion?

Tags: terminology

I'm not sure what to call a query that... isn't really a query; is "statement" a better word to use in place? Or how about "script"?

Or would something else be more appropriate?

Note: I've seen someone call it a "DELETE query" once

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I typically call them DML statements or just statements. Query is commonly used for convenience.

After all, you're issuing a query against the database - if you say...

```
DELETE dbo.table WHERE id = 5;
```

...isn't at least part of that a query? What about...

```
INSERT dbo.table1(col) SELECT col FROM dbo.table2 WHERE ...
```

?

And no, I would not call them "scripts" - that implies something else altogether (usually a collection of statements, in a wide variety of languages, and commonly saved to a file).

Comment: I generally use "statement" or "operation".

Comment: @REW strictly speaking, I interpret `operation` as the effect of the statement, not the statement itself. A `DELETE` operation physically happens because a `DELETE` statement was issued. The statement on its own does not cause an operation until someone executes it.